# How to use message converters with MessageListener in JMS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I am using JmsTemplate to convert and send event object. I have registered MappingJackson2MessageConverter with JmsTemplate.

```
Event event;
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, event);
```

I am using `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and getting messages from that topic. I don't know how to convert this message back to my object?

My messageconverter for JmsTemplate is

```
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
```

I have tried calling `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` and passed this message object to convert, but it didn't work out. 
How can I convert my message object I recieved to the custom object I want to?

```
@Bean
        public DefaultMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
            DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
            container.setDestinationName(COMMENT_QUEUE);
            container.setPubSubDomain(true);
            container.setMessageListener(new AcListenerSubscriber());
            container.start();

            return container;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageConverter` is only applied when you use the `@JmsListener` annotation to create the listener.

In the case of a `MessageListener` like your `AcListenerSubscriber` it is ignored.